# Python making a dictionary

Tags: python

I'm new to learning python, and I am trying to code a small word translator from English to Spanish. I got code here that translates from both English to Spanish and Spanish to English. However, I want to add in code that allows the user to see the word list when they enter 'show'. I got code for it but when I type in show, it just prints out the "except keyerror".

```
english_list = ["fire","apple","morning","river","wind"]
spanish_list = ["fuego","manzana","mañana","río","viento"]
english_to_spanish = dict(zip(english_list, spanish_list))

def translate(word):
    try:
        for key,value in english_to_spanish.items():
            if key == word:
                print("{0} in Spanish is {1}".format(
                                             word, english_to_spanish[word]))
            elif value == word:
                print("{0} in English is {1}".format(
                                             word, key))          
    except KeyError:
        print("That wasn't an option"
            .format(translate))

print("Welcome to the English <--> Spanish Dictionary")
while True:
    word1 = input("> ")
    translate(word1)
```

Here is the code I thought would work to show the user the word list when they type in 'show.'

```
if word == 'show':
    wordlist = input("Would you like to see the English or Spanish wordlist?")
    if wordlist == 'english':       
        print(english_list)
    elif wordlist == 'spanish':
            print(spanish_list)
    else:
        print("That wasnt an option")
```

It would be greatly appreciated if someone could help me out here. 
Thanks

Comment: Of course "show" raises a key error - it's not in the list. The code posted at the bottom Should Work (*assuming* that `translate` is not called and it is put at the appropriate location). Showing the *actual code* is important.

Comment: Your original code uses `word1`, not `word`, for user input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
english_list = ["fire","apple","morning","river","wind"]
spanish_list = ["fuego","manzana","mañana","río","viento"]
english_to_spanish = dict(zip(english_list, spanish_list))
spanish_to_english = dict(zip(spanish_list, english_list))

def translate(word):
    translation = english_to_spanish.get(word)
    if translation:
        return translation

    translation = spanish_to_english.get(word)
    if translation:
        return translation

    raise Exception('Word {0} does not exists'.format(word))

print("Welcome to the English <--> Spanish Dictionary")
while True:
    word = input("> ")
    if word == 'show':
        wordlist = input("Would you like to see the English or Spanish wordlist?")
        if wordlist == 'english':
            print ','.join(english_list)
        elif wordlist == 'spanish':
            print ','.join(spanish_list)
    else:
        try:
            translate(word)
        except Exception as e:
            print str(e)
```

This should work, but not tested.

I added spanish_english dict because in your solution you do an iteration for each lookup in the dictionary.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but why do I get a invalid syntax error on the the last line of your code print str(e)?

Answer (score 1):

The answer of @gosom is almost right except for some little mistakes:

1. quit a ':' at the end of line "if word == 'show'"
2. if you are using Python 2.x, you should replace the 'input' to 'raw_input'

The code below has been tested on Python 2.7.3:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

english_list = ["fire","apple","morning","river","wind"]
spanish_list = ["fuego","manzana","mañana","río","viento"]
english_to_spanish = dict(zip(english_list, spanish_list))
spanish_to_english = dict(zip(spanish_list, english_list))

def translate(word):
    translation = english_to_spanish.get(word)
    if translation:
        return translation

    translation = spanish_to_english.get(word)
    if translation:
        return translation

    raise Exception('Word {0} does not exists'.format(word))

print("Welcome to the English <--> Spanish Dictionary")
while True:
    word = raw_input("> ")
    if word == 'show':
        wordlist = raw_input("Would you like to see the "
                             "English or Spanish wordlist?")
        if wordlist == 'english':
            print ','.join(english_list)
        elif wordlist == 'spanish':
            print ','.join(spanish_list)
    else:
        try:
            translate(word)
        except Exception as e:
            print '--'
            print str(e)
```